# Relative Layout issues

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Hi I am having trouble with my Relative Layout and would appreciate if anyone could give me advice please as I been trying multiple ways and my map fragment seems to stay the same size.

This is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="@color/BlanchedAlmond">  

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/stopActivityButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="257dp"
    android:onClick="endActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/stopbutton" />

<fragment        
    android:id="@+id/map"  
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/stopActivityButton"      
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/> 

<TextView        
    android:id="@+id/tvActivityTitle"        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:textSize="32sp" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/map"
    android:text="@string/activityTitle"
    android:gravity="left"/>

<TextView        
    android:id="@+id/tvActivity"        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"       
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:textSize="15sp" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/map"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvActivityTitle"
    android:gravity="center"/>

  <TextView        
    android:id="@+id/tvActivityConfidenceTitle"        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:textSize="32sp" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/map"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvActivity"
    android:text="@string/tvActivityConfidenceTitle"
    android:gravity="left"/>

<TextView        
    android:id="@+id/tvActivityConfidence"        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:textSize="15sp" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/map"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvActivityConfidenceTitle"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<TextView        
    android:id="@+id/tvDurationTitle"        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:textSize="32sp" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/map"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvActivityConfidence"
    android:text="@string/tvDurationTitle"
    android:gravity="left"/> 

 <TextView        
    android:id="@+id/tvDuration"        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:textSize="15sp" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/map"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvDurationTitle"
    android:gravity="center"/> 

 <Chronometer 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/chrono"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvDuration"/>

  <TextView        
    android:id="@+id/tvDistanceTitle"        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:textSize="32sp" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/map"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chrono"
    android:text="@string/tvDistanceTitle"
    android:gravity="left"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It looks like so at the moment:

[image]

However I would like it to look something like this:

[image]

Comment: What is your question? can you explain?

Comment: @HamidShatu I am trying to get the map fragment into the top right hand corner and the Stop Activity button along the bottom like the second image. I have tried setting the align to bottom for the button but the map does not move so that the button is half hidden.

Comment: Please post your output image big properly.\

Comment: Did you try placing `ImageButton` as `android:layout_below = @id/map` ?

Comment: @NatalieCarr You can use Linear layout..

Comment: @PiyushGupta do you mean instead of Relative or within the Relative layout?

Comment: @NatalieCarr Instead of Relative layout using weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ff0000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="#000000" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvActivityTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="activityTitle"
            android:textSize="32sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvActivity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvActivityTitle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvActivityConfidenceTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvActivity"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="tvActivityConfidenceTitle"
            android:textSize="32sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvActivityConfidence"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvActivityConfidenceTitle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDurationTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvActivityConfidence"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="tvDurationTitle"
            android:textSize="32sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDuration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvDurationTitle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/chrono"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvDuration"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDistanceTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chrono"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="tvDistanceTitle"
            android:textSize="32sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".8" />
 </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="#c0c0c0"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:background="#c0c0c0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/stopActivityButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:onClick="endActivity" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, was playing around but never would have gotten that :) Life saver :)

Answer (score 0):

The second picture is really small, but I assume that you would like to add some buttons (Facebook, Twitter, ...) in your activity?

You could add another `RelativeLayout`/`LinearLayout` in your layout and add inside the buttons. Set the `layout_alignmentParentBottom=true`.

Hope this helps you!